# I am getting indexOutOfBoundsException whenever I try to get the value on my table and use it on `setString`

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I cant get the data on my table when using `setString()` method it says that indexOutOfBoundsException

```
String upd = "update sinfo set sname = ?, course = ?, section = ?, dob = ?, address = ? where sid = ?";
String sc = course.getSelectedItem().toString();
TableModel model = sTable.getModel();
int i = sTable.getSelectedRow();

pst = conn.prepareStatement(upd);

pst.setString(1, sn.getText());
pst.setString(2, sc);
pst.setString(3, ss.getText());
pst.setString(4, db.getText());
pst.setString(5, ad.getText());
pst.setString(6, model.getValueAt(i,0).toString()); //I get the error here saying indexOutOfBoundsException: -1

pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Post the actual error statement and the line that is causing the problem. Maybe the issue is with the "i" variable because you don't have a selected row?

Comment: I already selected a row and then when I try to do the function, I get the error on pst.setString(6, model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it, camickr is right. Whenever I select a row on a table, the selected row will reset. And that is the cause of the error. Thank you and sorry because im new to programming and using this site